# Is it free to create an Ubuntu One Account?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I just created an Ubuntu One account, but I am unsure; is the account ITSELF free?

Comment: Were you asked to pay anything?

Comment: I didn't _think_ that I would be charged for the account, I just wanted to confirm. God bless. :)

Comment: What are you using Ubuntu One for ? Many of the services were shut down : https://blog.ubuntu.com/2014/04/02/shutting-down-ubuntu-one-file-services . The wiki page "https://login.ubuntu.com/terms/#fees-and-payment" has not been updated since 1/2014 and is thus outdated.

Answer (score 6):

Refer to the **Fees and payment** section of the Ubuntu One TOS at https://login.ubuntu.com/terms/#fees-and-payment:

> The Ubuntu One services consist of a free and paid subscriptions. An
>   Ubuntu One subscription is required for all services and a valid
>   credit card is required for paid subscriptions.

You have a free subscription. Without providing a credit card, you can't get a paid subscription.

> If you purchase content or applications from us, payment for content
>   or applications is due at the time you purchase the content or
>   application. You will be asked to enter your credit card number and we
>   will charge your credit card at the time of purchase.

You'll know if you get charged since payment won't happen silently.

Comment: That wiki page has not been updated since January 2014 . The scope of Ubuntu One was updated April 2014 - https://blog.ubuntu.com/2014/04/02/shutting-down-ubuntu-one-file-services and thus some of the content on the wiki page you linked is outdated (just a little FYI)

Answer (score 0):

**The Ubuntu One account itself is free.**

I have retained an Ubuntu One account since 2013, without a credit card attached, as well as without a charge.

Ubuntu One has a number of free services that I use (haven't explored their pay services).

The ones that I use are for web authentication, such as provided by many social sites such as Facebook, Google, Launchpad, and a few others.

While I prefer not to use social sites for login authentications, but the actual site that I'm logging into, I do use it for some sites such as:

- ubuntuforums.org
- launchpad.net
- pastebin.ubuntu.com

... and a few others.

**An Ubuntu One account is a requirement** for logging into the official Ubuntu Web forum. (Note: [Askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com) is presented by http://www.ubuntu.com as one of their official support sites.)

You can explore many of the services both free and paid services by visiting http://www.ubuntu.com and clicking on one of the menu links included in the first to line header of the site.  Some of the link names include:

- Design
- Hardware
- Partners
- Shop
- cloud
- Server

... and more.

**Your account itself is free**.  You would only pay for something that you explicitly order as a paid product or service.